# JSTL questions (Spring 3)

Tags: spring, jstl

I'm trying to get my spring application working, following a guy who posted an example with earlier spring version. I've been having many problems with his example so I'm not posting a link so as not to lead anyone else astray. Fighting through issues, I was able to get to the point where things are working. Somewhat. I have not been able to figure out the following two things:

1. `$(message)` isn't printing the message which is a bean of type String.
2. `<c:out value="${message}"` prints the message but only if I add `<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` to the jsp. I would assume that adding jtslview class to the resolver would be enough. It's not. What's wrong here?

setup

```
  Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers    1.4.1.20110909-1818 epp.package.jee 
  Tomcat 7
  Spring 3 distribution (all jars in /lib)
  lib/jstl-1.2.jar
```

jsp in question

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Message View</title> 
</head>
<body>
    $(message)
    <br>
    message=$(message);
    <br>
    message=<c:out value="${message}" />
</body>
</html>
```

this prints the following. The message "bean" is clearly passed to the page.

```
$(message) 
message=$(message); 
message=Hello World from Spring MVC!
```

web.xml

```
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"    
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"    
        id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="2.5">    

        <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>    
        <welcome-file-list>        
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>    
        </welcome-file-list>     

        <servlet>        
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>        
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
        </servlet>    

        <servlet-mapping>        
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>        
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>    
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">     

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.helloworldexample.controllers" />     

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

controller (just in case)

```
package com.helloworldexample.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class MesssageController {


@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView handleHello() {
    String message="Hello World from Spring MVC!";

    return new ModelAndView("messageView", "message", message);

}

@RequestMapping("/welcome.html")
public ModelAndView handleWelcome() {
    String message="Welcome in Spring MVC!";

    return new ModelAndView("messageView", "message", message);

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the JSP expression language is `${some expression}`. Not `$(some expression)`.

Each time you use a JSP tag, its tag library **must** be declared in the JSP. The fact that you configure Spring to use a JstlView has nothing todo with the possibility of using the `<c>` tags. It just configures Spring to perform appropriate actions before dispatching to the view.

`<c:out>` should always be used to render a string, unless you're absolutely sure that the string doesn't contain any character that must be HTML-escaped. Not using it opens the door to attacks where a user could submit a text containing `</html>` or a piece of javascript code that would compromise your web site.

Read the official tutorial about servlets and JSPs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

Comment: The braces work. Point taken on the tag lib definition (no idea how the example author got his stuff to work without it). Thanks for the tip on c:out. True expert!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to change your import tagslib

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

to

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="htttp://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```